# How to automatically create another file that matches a regex based on a file created?

Tags: files

Suppose I create a file in `dir1/file1.txt`. As soon as I write the file for the first time, I want to create another file in `dir2/file1_friend.txt`. But when I create a file `dir1/file2.txt`, I want the new file created be `dir2/file2_friend.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `before-save-hook` for this. Note this runs on every buffer save, so we have some checks to make sure we have a buffer file name, that it ends with the right string, and that your new file doesn't already exist. then, if all that is ok, we make the file.

```
(require 'f)
(require 's)

(defun custom-save ()
  (let ((bf (buffer-file-name))
        (bff "my_file_abc_friend.txt"))
    (when (and bf
           (s-ends-with? "dir1/my_file_abc.txt" bf)
           (not (file-exists-p bff)))
      ;; I think this means you are in dir1 so we can just make the desired file      
      (with-temp-file bff
    ;; add contents here if you want
    ))))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'custom-save)
```

Comment: The point of "abc" was that if the file that is originally saved is "gfh", then the other file should be gfh_friend etc.

Comment: you probably have to be a lot more specific about your regex, or you will get *_friend.txt* files for every kind of text file. What is the real pattern you are looking for? Is it just dir1/*.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Here the "need a friend" suffix is _blah.txt.You'd probably want to make it a defvar and maybe include some directory path. But .... it works.

```
  (defun friend-file-root-name(f)
    (string-match  "\\(.*\\)\\(_blah.txt\\)" f)
    (match-string 1 f)
    )

  (defun custom-save-create-friend-file ()
    (message "in custom save")
    (when (friend-file-root-name (buffer-file-name))
      (let ((friend-file (concat (friend-file-root-name (buffer-file-name)) "_friend.txt")))
        (message "potential friend file is: %s" friend-file)
        (unless (file-exists-p friend-file)
          (with-temp-file friend-file
            (message "need to create %s" friend-file)
            (save-buffer)
            )))))

  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'custom-save-create-friend-file)
```

Comment: Would you please explain how to use this code?

Comment: The custom save hook looks to match a "spec" for your - file see the (string-match ..) call. Then if there is a match it replaces the "_blah.txt" with "friend.txt" and creates that file if it doesnt already exist. You should be able to work from that and change accordingly.